# If Function with Multiple Text Criteria in Same Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I've got an google sheet that I copy paste into an excel sheet.
One of the columns in the google sheet contains options that a client selected out of; Lift Pass, Rentals, Lessons, and Helmet 
The selected options (Lift Pass, Helmet, Rentals, Lessons) are in one cell, with the client info in separate cells.

What I'm trying to do is have an If function return 1 if certain products are selected. 
Currently I can get the function to work if there's only one product selected (I.e. "Lift Pass" only), but I can't figure out how to make it work with multiple products selected.

My working functions:

Lesson Only:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(OR('Paste Here'!B2="Lift Pass",'Paste Here'!B2="Rentals")),'Paste Here'!B2="Lessons"),1,"")
```

Rental Only:

```
=IF(AND('Paste Here'!B2="Rentals",NOT(OR('Paste Here'!B2="Lift Pass",'Paste Here'!B2="Lessons"))),1,"")
```

Lift Pass only:

```
=IF(AND('Paste Here'!B2="Lift Pass",NOT(OR('Paste Here'!B2="Rentals",'Paste Here'!B2="Lessons"))),1,"")
```

The products are listed in the B:B column. I've tried a SUMIF, COUNTIF and a few others only to receive #VALUE back. Each client should end up with a 1 under the column that specifies what products they've ordered.

This is the data I'm working with:

[image]

Help?

Comment: Please share/show your (sample)data

Comment: I can't really say I understand what you are trying to do, but I think if I had your problem I would do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APND2.png), or if I needed to know what the selection was exactly in words instead of having to look at 4 columns, then use different 'scores' for each item instead of using 1 everywhere which will allow me to use a lookup, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWiha.png) (you see the Ref 1 corresponds to lesson only, 2 to rental only, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If your formula is on google sheets, use [`REGMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en).
If your formula is in Excel, then use [`SEARCH`](https://exceljet.net/formula/if-cell-contains).

The example I set up was to enter "Rentals, Helmet, Lessons" into cell A1.

- In google sheets then, in cell B1 I used the formula `=if(REGEXMATCH(A1,"Helmet"),1,"")`.
- In Excel then, in cell B1 I used the formula `=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("Helmet",A1),0)>0,1,"")`

The `SEARCH` formula will return an error if the string is not found in the cell, so it must be handled similar to the example.

You can stack these up in `If` statements as much as needed. As an example, if you need to detect if three of the products are present, stack up the `IF` statements (in Excel) like this:

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("helmet",A1),0)>0,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("rental",A1),0)>0,IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("lift pass",A1),0)>0,1,""),""),"")
```

Comment: I'm getting #NAME? I use excel 2007 if that has anything to do with it :/

Comment: Your question was referring to google sheets, so I assumed that's where the formula was located. In that case, see the updated answer above.

Comment: It's ok, I really appreciate your help! I'm trying to get a result for when Lift Pass, Rentals AND helmet are listed, should I use multiple IF or AND? The below AND is returining #VALUE
`=IF(SEARCH(AND("Lift Pass","Rental","Helmet"),'Paste Here'!B2)>0,1,"")`

Comment: Try the formula above to handle detecting three products, and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: So far so good! How can I get it to return a blank instead of FALSE? When I add another IF it returns #VALUE! again :(

Comment: You do have to take care how you embed the `IF` statements. I extended the multi-level FALSE checks at the end to show a blank for all conditions.

Comment: You're Awesome!

Last but not least, how can I get it to return FALSE if I need to exclude products?
I.E. Both "Lift, Lessons, Rentals" and "Lift, Lessons" show as 1 under the Lift & Lessons column and the Full Package (all 3) column

Comment: For the condition you want to exclude, just change the `>0` to `=0` and that term will be excluded.

Comment: LOL just consider an upvote and accepting this answer as solved is fine :)